Conditional Formatting Rules applying in background
I would like to create a function where conditional formatting rules are being applied whenever a particular sheet is being edited. Basically, I have a form recieving data, and then I have a script  and formulas working to add a check mark to a sheet if the data has been submitted
Sheet where data is being added:  Data Responses
Sheet where conditional formatting is being applied: Accountability Sheet
Here is the project
I want the conditional formatting to look for 'False' and color the cell red, and then if it is anything else color the cell green.
I have tried using copilot and chatgpt to help me, but I cannot seem to get the correct code.
I have tried an onedit function (which I think is correct) but it keeps telling me that source is undefined.

Can you please share your script in your post as your file only has a view only setting (we cannot view your bound script this way).

Welcome to StackOverflow. It seems like your code is already working. May I ask if you wish to use OnFormSubmit instead? Where everytime someone submits a form, the code will automatically run.

Conditional formatting rules can usually be set up once and for all, and seldom need to be updated dynamically. Is this an XY problem?

To recap: 1. Code is working, 2. No need to keep recreating the same rules and performing round trips onedit. and Now #3. "source is undefined" is often caused by running the onEdit() script in from the console.

The onEdit script probably requires the  event object from the onEdit trigger but since we don't have an example we cannot be sure. Provide [mcve]
